# Cannot find controls after using FindFirst or FindAll methods for AutomationElement

Tags: wpf, ui-automation

I automate ui test for wpf application.
I trying to find controls, after make some steps, but allways when i use FindFirst or FindAll methods, many controls in window is lost. Now, i did an experiment:
Part one:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\application.exe");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Condition windowCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Window Title");

AutomationElement window = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindChildByCondition(windowCondition);
window.SetFocus();
int x = 512;
int y = 384;
SetCursorPos(x, y);

// Click on coordinates:
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
```

After that, i can find all controls that i need, and all tools(UISpy, UIAVerify ant others) can find all controls.

Part 2:
i add only 2 strings:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\application.exe");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Condition windowCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Window Title");

AutomationElement window = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindChildByCondition(windowCondition);

// New strings here:
Condition controlCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "ConnectButton");
AutomationElement control = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, controlCondition);

window.SetFocus();
int x = 512;
int y = 384;
SetCursorPos(x, y);

// Click on coordinates:
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
```

And now, i can find those controls are not really visible, and those that are visible - not detected.

Whats wrong?
thx

Comment: When using UISpy, do you see differences in the control detection in Raw vs. Control vs. Content views?

Comment: I've got a similar problem, but I failed to minimize it to a simple recreateable test case. :( - I'll be glad to hear if you found anything to shed light on this.